# Deducing $t_1 = t_2 \land t_2 = t_3 \Rightarrow t_1 = t_3$ with special axioms of equality.

Tags: first-order-logic

In Manin's "Mathematical Logic for Mathematicians," the beginning section is dedicated to syntactic properties of various first-order languages. I've found a strong weakness of mine is in close syntactic manipulation, so I'm struggling with the direct deduction proofs.

To clarify, a *deduction* of $P$ in $\mathcal{E} \subset L \in \mathcal{L}_1$ (first-order languages), written $\mathcal{E} \vdash P$, is a sequence of formulae in $\mathcal{E}$ where either $P$ is in $\mathcal{E}$, or can be obtained from $\mathcal{E}$ via deductive rules. For example, $(P, P \Rightarrow Q, Q)$ is a deduction of $Q$ from $\{P, P \Rightarrow Q\}$.

Other valid rules that have been derived are simple predicate manipulations, such as $\forall x(P) \Rightarrow P(t)$.

Right now I'm a little stumped on a derivation of $t_1 = t_2 \land t_2 = t_3 \Rightarrow t_t = t_3$ using:

- The deductive rules of MP and Universal Generalizaton, and Conjunction,
- Basic predicate manipulations,
- The rules $x=x$ for all variables $x$, and $x=y \Rightarrow \{P(x,x) \Rightarrow P(x,y)\}$ for atomic predicates $P$.

I believe the proof should go something along the lines of:

1. List out some premises, such as the second axiom in the third bullet.
2. Create some tautologies that get me from those true premises to $x=y \land y=z \Rightarrow x=z$.
3. Generalize then instantiate over $t_1, t_2, t_3$.

But I can't figure out (2). If someone could give a hint, I'd be appreciative. I have solutions with more flexible techniques such as proof by contradiction, but I think the intent of these types of exercises is that they're strict deduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the trick is this: if you have $t_1 = t_2$ and $t_2 = t_3$, then with $P(x, y)$ defined to be $t_1 = y$, you can use the rule $x = y \Rightarrow P(x, x) \Rightarrow P(x, y)$ to transform $t_1 = t_2$ into $t_1 = t_3$. (The first argument of $P$ is actually irrelevant here.)

Comment: Thanks! It didn't occur to me that I could consider a unary predicate as binary, but that makes sense.